# How to get value stored in type property of NSTextAttachment?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

```
class AKAttachement: NSTextAttachment{

    var tag:Int!
    var frame: CGRect!
    var type: String!
    var url: URL?

    var completionHandler:((CGRect)->Void)?


    func configure(type:String, tag:Int,frame:CGRect,_url:URL?) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.type = type
        self.url = _url
        self.frame = frame
    }

    override func attachmentBounds(for textContainer: NSTextContainer?, proposedLineFragment lineFrag: CGRect, glyphPosition position: CGPoint, characterIndex charIndex: Int) -> CGRect {
        let superRect = super.attachmentBounds(for: textContainer, proposedLineFragment: lineFrag, glyphPosition: position, characterIndex: charIndex)
        completionHandler?(lineFrag)
        print(lineFrag)

        return superRect

    }
}
```

I am storing data in properties and Attaching it into `NSAttributedString` 
When I am trying to get object of `AKAttachment` subclass `NSTextAttachment`.

I am able to get the Object.
But getting the **type** property as nil.

Comment: Are you sure you have set it? Or you're supposed it must be set somewhere by `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: I am configuring AKattchement by setting the values into the properties.
Then I am attaching it into NSAttributed String 
By Using NSAttributedString(attachment:objAttachment)

After this I am saving it in coredata by using transformable data.

After this I am tring to extract it from coredata as NSAttributedString and I am getting this. But When I am enumerating it by using enumrating method of attributed string I am getting AkAttachment but I am not getting property of AKAttachment.

Comment: `NSCoder` protocol methods are required to be implemented. Have you done that? Would you provider the whole class code listing, please?

Comment: yes I have implemented both the methods but I didn't get any solution

Comment: I need the whole class code listing. And translating to and from the transformable NSData.